# iPhone:Server response parsing issues

Tags: iphone

The below is my server response. I would like to parse and use it further.

responseString:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "MyData": [
        {
            "Value": 1,
            "Name": "David",
            "MusicURL": "http://www.mycomany.net/musicoutput/song1.wav",
            "ImageURL": "http://www.mycomany.net/imageout/david.png"
        },
        {
            "Value": 2,
            "Name": "Martin",
            "MusicURL": "http: //www.mycomany.net/musicoutput/song1.wav",
            "ImageURL": "http: //www.mycomany.net/imageout/martin.png"
        },
        {
            "Value": 3,
            "Name": "Steve",
            "MusicURL": "http: //www.mycomany.net/musicoutput/song1.wav",
            "ImageURL": "http: //www.mycomany.net/imageout/david.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

The below is my code for trying further to parse and use it. BUT, the issue is, its not getting parsed from NSJSONSerialization, instead i'm getting NULL. Printing as responseDict:(null) ; jsonError: (null).

**Please Note**,when i'm doing like this->NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; , i'm getting response string as the above output. But, i want it as NSDictionary for my further use.

Please help to resolve this issue.

NSMutableData *webData;

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
    //    [self callGetGroup];    
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{    
    [webData appendData:data];
}

        -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {

        NSData *theResponseData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:webData];
            if (theResponseData)
            {
    //NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     //NSLog(@"responseString:%@ ;", responseString);
                NSError *jsonError;
                NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theResponseData options:0 error:&jsonError];

        NSLog(@"responseDict:%@ ; jsonError: %@", responseDict, jsonError); // Printing as responseDict:(null) ; jsonError: (null)

        [self handleResponse :responseDict];

            }
        }


        -(void) handleResponse :(NSDictionary *) responsedata
        {
            NSString* value = NULL;

            for (id key in responsedata)
            {
                NSDictionary *currentDict = (NSDictionary *) [responsedata objectForKey:key];
                value = (NSString*)[currentDict objectForKey:@"status"];

                if ( [value intValue]==1) // success
                {

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Is that `responseString:` part of the server response or is that output from an `NSLog`?

Comment: How are you initializing `webData` that you are referencing in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`?

Comment: Hi, I updated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what the error was.

Anyway, there is a mistake in the JSON Feed, so there is most likely a parsing error. If the JSON is not correct, the resulting object will be `nil`. Output from [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/):

```
Parse error on line 13:
...        "MusicURL": http: //mycpmany.net
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Comment: The `NSError` object was null, as stated in the code comments. I think that the missing quote is a typo on the OP's part, since the other two objects don't have that problem.

Comment: Yeah, but it was off the page to the right... Still, this should fix it.

Comment: No problems with the json response, its valid only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the "key"is not the object for the value in resposeDictionary, the ResposeDictionary holds more dictionaries from the look of the data. So your "key" is not the key to a value, it's a dictionary. It's a little hard to read the output the way it's written in the question but:

```
for (id object in responsedata)
{
    NSDictionary *currentDict = (NSDictionary *)object;
    value = (NSString*)[currentDict valueForKey:@"status"];
    if ( [value length] > 0) // success
    {
        NSLog(@"Success! Status:%@",value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I said i am not even getting response in NSDictionary in connectionDidFinishLoading, so i can forget about checking for success value now.

Comment: Are you initializing NSMutableData *webData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];?